# Finding volume of a solid made by cross sections.

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

> The base of a solid is bounded by the functions $f(x)=\cos(x)$ and $g(x)=x^2$. If the cross-sections perpendicular to the $x$-axis are semicircles, what is the volume of the solid?

I solved it by integrating (pi/2)(r)^2 between the bound (-.824,.824) where r is the difference in the two curves f(x) = cos(x) and g(x) = x^2, however I got 1.374, which is incorrect. Can anyone please point out any mistakes I made?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Your "r", the distance between the two curves, is the [b]diameter[/b] of the semi-circle not its radius!

Comment: Also, you have semicircles, not full circles, so integrate just $\frac 12 \pi r^2=\frac \pi8(g(x)-f(x))^2$